# SONAR integration with Jenkins. ERROR: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am getting this error after running SONAR analysis in Jenkins with SonarQube.
After the build is running a while and analysing I am getting the error.
I have to mention that I've created the token in Sonar and put it in Jenkins configuration.

Somehow, I think it's due to the missing rights on Sonar to create a project or something.

Can you please help me with a solution?

Here are the latest logs from the Jenkins build.

```
WARN: This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
INFO: 328 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 868 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 818ms, dir size=42 MB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 2897ms, zip size=6 MB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2:36.346s
INFO: Final Memory: 30M/313M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a connection issue, it's a permission issue (**Authorization**).

The posted message indicated `ERROR: You're not authorized to run analysis.`

Check if your user has **[Execute Analysis permission](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/#header-4)** (see Global or Project permissions).

If this is a new project (does not yet exist SonarQube), then users will also need **"Create Projects"** to create the initial project inside SonarQube. This can be done in advance via the UI (or by an Admin) or on first run, depending on permission model.

Review the [SonarQube Security](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/) page and provide only what's needed.

See special note on **Creators permission** under [Permission Templates for Default Permissions | Creators permissions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/#header-5).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I assume it's not connectivity issue. But I would kindly ask if this goes directly to the permission or may be something else. Thank you.

Comment: I can't answer that; my permissions were set up fine from Day 1, so never saw the error. Your only choices are connectivity, authentication (login) and authorization (roles/perms). You made it past the first two I assume. SQ permissions are limited.Can you "create project" (if not created), "execute analyis", and that's about it other than administration roles.

Comment: In my case the trick was to give the user (group) "create project" permission (either globally or per-project). This permission is only required for the very first initial scan it seems.

Comment: @IanW I'm just a bystander here. If you want your answer accepted, summon the user who asked the question.

Comment: @AttilaCsipak, oops!

Comment: @dragos-roban, updated the answer to include "Create Projects" for initial run (and fixed typos). Care to mark as accepted so it can be referred to in other posts as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Update: The issue was regarding to the Sonar rights.
After having admin rights, the build passed.

Comment: Admin is far too broad (dangerous) a permission just to perform analysis. Review the [SonarQube Security](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/) page and provide only what's needed.